# ui-router optional param without trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So this seems like a common problem but I haven't found any definite answer.
Basically I have a state:

```
.state('users', {
     url: '/example/:id',
        templateUrl: 'angular-views/example.html',
        controller: 'ExampleCtrl'
    })
```

I want id to be optional.

Sure it matches

```
example/
example/1234
```

But it doesn't match without trailing slash.

```
example
```

I tried `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);`, but that does not seem to work for this case. I could use `example?param=1234`, but I prefer the cleaner version.

Do I really need to define a second state for this to work?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can define optional URL parameters by giving them a default value in the `params` object, like this.  `squash` will hide the parameter in links if it's not defined.

```
.state('users', {
         url: '/example/:id',
            templateUrl: 'angular-views/example.html',
            controller: 'ExampleCtrl',
            params:  {
              id: {
                     value: null,
                     squash: true
                  }
                }
        });
```

I tried this locally and it seems to work OK regardless of trailing slash.

Comment: Does not work for me. Plz See the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/3aBchxk2nu6FiDrV3WNN?p=preview ... I used that squash but still <a href="#/posting//">Post 1</a> works fine because of trailing slashes but <a href="#/posting">Post 2</a> does not work at all

Comment: @Sami I'm not sure this will work with multiple squashable params.

Comment: But its not working for even single params when using `href` instead of `state`. Plz see https://plnkr.co/edit/3aBchxk2nu6FiDrV3WNN?p=preview

Comment: @Sami I'd recommend posting a separate question.  I'm not exactly sure what your problem is and I'm not really able to spend too much time looking right now.

Comment: No problem dear. Yes I already have a separate question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39082825/angular-url-without-slash-with-optional-parameters