# Angular Url without slash with optional parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, optional-parameters

Both [ui-router optional param without trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840896/ui-router-optional-param-without-trailing-slash)
and [How to define optional parameter using UI-Router without trailing slash as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30720672/how-to-define-optional-parameter-using-ui-router-without-trailing-slash-as-well) have insufficient arguments and invalid (at least for my scenario i.e. working links (href) for angular routes without trailing slashes) answers .

[**Live Demo Link**](https://plnkr.co/edit/3aBchxk2nu6FiDrV3WNN?p=preview)

Here are the example html links

```
 <div>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a> 
    | <a href="#/posting/">Post 1</a>
    | <a href="#/posting">Post 2</a>
    | <a href="#/posting/sami">Post 3</a>
    | <a ui-sref="post">Post 4</a>
    | <a ui-sref="post({nam:'sami'})">Post 5</a>        
</div>
```

All of the above links are working fine except **Post 2** because I have an optional parameter and so the link needs at least a slash at the end

I am using `stateprovider` and a `state` looks like

```
name: 'post',
val: {
    url : '/posting/:nam',
    views: {
        v1: {
         template: '<h4>Posting <label ng-if="stateParams.nam">{{stateParams.nam}}</label> </h4>',
         controller: 'post',
            resolve: {
              deps: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load([{ name: appName, files: ['post.js'] }]);
              }
            }
        },
        params: {
            nam: { squash: true, value: null }
        }
    }
 }
```

**How can i have a valid link without trailing slash** if I have only option to use links `href` and not the `ui-sref`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);` in config

Answer (score 0):

In case you like me tried @egor.xyz solution, and it didn't work. check the  [ui-router Frequent Questions](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-make-a-trailing-slash-optional-for-all-routes), and you will find the following:

> For older version of ui-router, add this snippet to your module's config function. It creates a rule on $urlRouterProvider that maps all urls that are missing a trailing slash to the same url but with the trailing slash appended.

```
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
    var path = $location.url();

    // check to see if the path already has a slash where it should be
    if (path[path.length - 1] === '/' || path.indexOf('/?') > -1) {
        return;
    }

    if (path.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        return path.replace('?', '/?');
    }

    return path + '/';
});
```

Worked for me.